# How to make a contact sheet from a multi page PDF

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to make a contact sheet from a multi page PDF. The output doesn't have to be a contact sheet per se. I am only looking for an automated way to place all of the pages from a PDF into a single document like a contact sheet.

My only thought would be to export all of the pages into their own document.

**What I have tried**

- I have tried Photoshop Automate Contact Sheet
- I have also tried Adobe Bridge Output Workspace

**What happens when I do one of the above**

It makes the contact sheet but is only placing the first page from the multi page PDF.

**Question**

How can I place multiple pages from 1 PDF file into a 1 page document like a contact sheet?

Comment: Your idea of exporting the pages from the PDF document and then creating the contact sheet makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagemagick's [`montage`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) command automatically handles pdf pages as separate images and outputs a grid. The following command outputs a grid of images that are:

1. On a black background
2. Opened at 600 pixels on their largest dimension (twice the target size)
3. Auto-resized to 300 pixels on their largest
   dimension (target size for each tile)
4. With a 3 pixel padding.

   ```
   montage \
   -background '#000000' \
   -define pdf:fit-page=600x00 \
   -resize 300x300 \
   -geometry +3+3 \
   inputFilename.pdf \
   outputFilename.jpg
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I had to replace `600x00` with `A4` for this to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have kind of lost track on whether Adobe continues to bundle a PDF printer driver, but if you have a PDF printer driver, you can simply use Acrobat to print multiple pages per sheet.

In the print dialog, you will see this option in the drop-down under **page scaling**. Once selected, you will have options to configure the rows, columns, and order pages vertical/horizontal.

You can then print to the PDF printer wrapper to create a new PDF file or send it to an actual printer.

Comment: Yes distiller is still in the bundles.

Comment: did they pull it from mac os at one point in the recent past?

Comment: It only comes with a bundle with acrobat PRO DC, you can also directly do this in acrobat pro. Seems to be on school mac's cant be sure though.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF Creator printer also offers the page to sheet option.
Select PDF Creator as printer - Go to Printing Preferences  Layout tab Pages per sheet - Select: 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 12